# -swift- trouble passing parse object from map kit annotation to detailViewController using disclosure button in swift

Tags: swift, parse-platform, mkannotation, mkannotationview, pfobject

Please help, Im having trouble passing parse object from annotation Query to destinationViewController. When the user taps the annotation view it takes the user to the destinationVC, but it passes the same object no matter which annotation the user taps. I think it has something to do with the prepareForSegue function. Please let me know what Im doing wrong.

Heres my code:

```
class MapSearchViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!



var jobPosts = [PFObject]()
var jobPost: PFObject?


let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var currentLoc: PFGeoPoint! = PFGeoPoint()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //MARK new added code Start--

    self.mapView.delegate = self

    self.mapView.setUserTrackingMode(MKUserTrackingMode.Follow, animated: true)

    //MARK new added code End--

    self.locationManager.delegate = self

    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

    self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

    self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    //Snippet For Blue Current Location Dot:

    //self.mapView.showsUserLocation = true



}


//MARK: -- Location Delegate Methods

func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

    let location = locations.last

    let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)

    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1))

    self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)

    self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()


}


func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Errors: " + error.localizedDescription)
}



//MARK: OCT 26

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let annotationQuery = PFQuery(className: "JobPost")
    currentLoc = PFGeoPoint(location: locationManager.location)
    annotationQuery.whereKey("location", nearGeoPoint: currentLoc, withinMiles: 100)
    annotationQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (posts, error) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            print("Successful query for annotations")
            let jobPosts = posts as [PFObject]!

            for post in jobPosts {
                let point = post["location"] as! PFGeoPoint
                var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(point.latitude, point.longitude)
                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
                annotation.title = post["job"] as! String
                let pay = post["price"] as! String
                let payLabel = "\(pay)$"
                annotation.subtitle = payLabel
                let btn = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
                self.jobPost = post


            }
        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    var view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("annotationIdentifier")
    if view == nil {
        view = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "annotationIdentifier")
        view?.canShowCallout = true
        view?.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .DetailDisclosure)
    } else {
        view?.annotation = annotation
    }
    return view
}

var selectedAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation!

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        selectedAnnotation = view.annotation as? MKPointAnnotation
        performSegueWithIdentifier("annotationSender", sender: self)
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? JobDetailViewController {
        destination.currentObject = jobPost
    }
}
```

}

code for detailVC:

```
class JobDetailViewController: UIViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var jobTitleLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var distanceLabel: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var jobDescriptionContent: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var pictureImageView: UIImageView!


var jobPosts:[PFObject]!
var currentObject : PFObject?
var distance = "7"
var annotation = MKPointAnnotation()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.distanceLabel.text = "\(distance) miles away"

    if let object = currentObject {
        jobTitleLabel.text = object["job"] as! String
        priceLabel.text = object["price"] as! String
        jobDescriptionContent.text = object["description"] as! String
    }

}
```

Comment: It's looks like you have `jobPost` object that set in this line of code `self.jobPost = post` in method `viewDidAppear`. When `prepareForSegue` colling it allways has the last object value from `for post in jobPosts {...}` If you need to select object from `jobPosts` then you have to select it when user make action. Now it's looks like you allways set the last object to your `detailVC`

Comment: Ahh I see now, you are exactly right, it's grabbing the last object. How would I go about selecting the object when the user makes an action?

Comment: You can make subclass of `MKPointAnnotation` and use it on your map. You can create this objects in your `mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation)` method. To this subclass you can add field `jobPostsIndex` for example and set it to your index in `jobPosts` for every annotation that added to map. In `prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)` method you can get this index from `sender` and get object you need from your `jobPosts[index]`